# Call remote model method in server.js in loopback?

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, loopbackjs

I have loopback models with some methods. Some methods are remote methods and some of them are not remote methods.
In server.js I want to allow calls only to remote methods and access to non remote shoul dbe denied.

I have the following code in server.js. I can call remote method in this way but also can call systems method.

```
// POST request process route and calls remote method
app.post(remoteMethodName, function(req, res) {

   app.models.Model.remoteMethodName({}, function(err, items){
       callback(err, items);
   });

});
```

I also want check method's ACL too.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying you want code in your server side code to NOT be able to do things w/ models? As far as I know, all your server side code runs as is, and ACLs only come into play via the REST API. (afaik)

Comment: @RaymondCamden: Thanks raymond.Yes, something like this. I have application written in ExtJs and it use ext-direct. I want write route to connect my request to LoopBack Models.We have ext-direct for express but i want write LoopBack module. And this route check ACLs on server.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the model defined in Loopback, you can add your custom endpoints (routes) to the your-model.js. This automatically enabled the ACL check.
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/Remote+methods

You can also close down the autogenerated endpoints, by using the YourModel.disableRemoteMethod()
http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#model-disableremotemethod

Handling the route in the server.js breaks the inherit logic of Loopback, but if you really want that, you can check the ACL ad hoc with ACL.checkpermission()
http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#acl-checkpermission